# ASCII string encoding swopping data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Hi I am importing ascii text from rs232 everything works except that sometimes the some of the data gets swopped around as in the picture. Can anyone assist me to stop this from happening please. The the strings are terminated with \r\n [image: ascii text]

```
-(void)readBytesAvailable:(NSInteger)count {

uint8_t buffer[count];
NSString *s;

NSInteger bytesRead = [session read: buffer bufferLength: count];


if (bytesRead > 0) {

    s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:bytesRead encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding ];

    //Append the incomming strings to the text view
    MAGDataTextView.text = [MAGDataTextView.text stringByAppendingString:s];

    // Scroll to end of text view
    [MAGDataTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(MAGDataTextView.text.length, 0)];

}
if (MAGDataTextView.hasText) {
    [[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems objectAtIndex:0] setEnabled:YES]; //ViewLines Button

}
}
```

Comment: No one can help without seeing some code and having more information about text encoding being used.

Comment: What do you mean the data gets "swopped around"? I don't see any "swopped" text. It looks to me like the columns of data are not displaying correctly. You will need to provide a LOT more information if you want help parsing this data. Is it using tabs between fields? Spaces? What characters are swapped, and how can you tell that they are swapped?

Comment: Look at the STN column at 50 the string is 50,1,13,,,8,215650,,27275.9,9,0  I inserted commas for spaces. But the string should be 50,,,8,211,135650,,27275.9,9,0